# Why should we not delete a question about using a factory class instead of direct object construction?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This meta-question is about the following question on the main site:

[Why should I use a factory class instead of direct object construction? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/253254)

Currently, it has a lone delete vote. The only reason I noticed is because another user pinged me in a comment.

This question was closed as primarily opinion-based. However, I believe the question does have value. This is the type of question that new developers are prone to asking, and the accepted answer provides a very good explanation.

I edited the question to clean up the wording a bit and to phrase it better. Given that at least one person believes it should be deleted, what else should be done?

- Does it need additional editing and reopened?
- Should it stay closed, but not deleted?
- Should it be deleted?
- Should it be locked in some way? (I can never remember all the lock types we have now)
- Something else?

Comment: as far as I can tell, your recent edit invalidated [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/253295/31260) (not that I complain, answer is garbage and edit made question much better)

Comment: The question is now reopened.